# Dragging an item from listBox1 and droping the item into listBox2 code does not work(AllowDrop=true)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

Although both of the listBoxes `AllowDrop=true` `listBox2` does not allow me to drop an item from `listbox1` into `listBox2`.

VS 2022 does not give any error, warning or exception handling problem.
The problem is that this code does not do what it supposed to do. It does not let me carry 1 item from `listBox1` to `listBox2`.

```
namespace LISTBOX_fareileSURUKLEbirakDRAGDROP_Olaylari
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            listBox2.AllowDrop = true;

            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0) return;

            string deger = listBox1.Items[listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X,e.Y)].ToString();

            if (DoDragDrop(deger, DragDropEffects.All) == DragDropEffects.All)
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y));
        }
        private void listBox2_DragOver(object sender,DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect= DragDropEffects.All;
        }
        private void listBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
                listBox2.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat));
        }
    }
}
```

UI:
[image]

What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: Even though this is not the *canonical* way to do a Drag&Drop, it should work-ish anyway. Did you actually subscribe to those events? -- Just for testing, add to the Form Constructor: `listBox2.DragEnter += (s, e) => e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect; listBox2.DragDrop += (s, e) => (s as ListBox)?.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat));` (assuming `listBox2` is the one *on the right*, in the image you posted)

Comment: @Jimi How did you come to a conclusion that this code is  the code thay my code is lacking? I have never seen a code like what you wrote now.

Comment: Since - as mentioned - though it's not the *correct* way to handle a Drag&Drop operation, that code should kind of work anyway, might as well test whether the events are actually subscribed to. It appears they were not

Comment: Note that the snippet I've posted is also not correct (over-simplified), it's just for testing

Comment: @Jimi The event handlers were not attached to my listbox codes that's why this problem occured.

Answer (score 0):

The event handlers were not attached to my listbox codes that's why this problem occured.

Ones I attached them, the problem is solved.